# Loading properties in an array using Groovy Soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a property containing an array of data separated by comma as below:

> TESTCASE1,TESTCASE2,TESTCASE3

Now my objective is to only execute the testcases mentioned in the property and disable the rest of the testcases in the Project. So for this i have defined an array as below

```
// Define the array
def MAX_SIZE = 3
def myArray = new Object[MAX_SIZE]
```

I am struggling to find a way: to load these TESTCASES in an array and execute via a for loop to disable the Testcases not mentioned in the property.

Since I am running Soapui via command line in linux so there is no way i can execute more than 1 TESTCASES.

Comment: not a good way of controlling cases though as every time you have to add or remove cases from the property, instead store like this [TC1:true,TC2:false,TC3:true,TC4:true] so you will have all cases everytime in the property, and you just have to make true or false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i was able to do that:

```
def totalTestCases = testSuite.getTestCases().size();
def myArray = new Object[totalTestCases]

myArray = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "TESTCASES" ).tokenize( ',' )
```